# zeromq sub-pub mode, block and lost

Tags: block, zeromq

I use zeromq sub-pub mode in my app, but I got a problem:
I started sub app and subscribed the message, and then started pub app later, and the pub app will not publish any message in half hour or longer, after this, the pub app will pub messages to the sub-app, but the sub-app was blocked there without any message or some of the messages are lost.

If someone knows what's the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Publisher:#include "stdafx.h"
#include <zmq.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* server = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);

    zmq_bind(server, "tcp://192.168.1.212:5555");

    printf("wait for one and half hour\n");
    Sleep(1000*60*60*1.5);
    while(1)
    {
        char buffer[256] = {0};
        sprintf_s(buffer, "%s", "Hello World!");
        zmq_send(server, buffer, 256, 0);
        printf("send: %s\n", buffer);
        Sleep(1000*60);
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Subscriber:#include "stdafx.h"
#include <zmq.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    zmq_connect(socket, "tcp://202.101.xxx.xx:5555");
    zmq_setsockopt(socket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    while(1)
    {
        char buffer[256] = {0};
        zmq_recv(socket, buffer, 256, 0);
        printf("recv: %s\n", buffer);
    }
 return 0;
}

Comment: I think it's because I didn't set ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE in my socket, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should start the publisher first, then the subscribers.

Also, read this section in the guide regarding scenarios where messages between PUB and SUB can get lost: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out

Without any additional information, or code snippets of what you're doing, it's hard to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: actually, the code snippets are very easy, the pusblish side publish a message to subscriber every minute, and the subscriber subcribe the message. everything's ok when the publish side publish message every minutes, but when I add Sleep more than one hour before the publish side publish message, and after one hour later, it publish message, but now, the subcriber can not get any message. the two sides are on different internet machine, not internal network.